# Preparing an Android App for Release

Tags: dart, flutter

First off,nothing i enter into the terminal in vscode works,there's always an error
But when i enter this:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

into the terminal the following message pops up:

```
keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

When i enter the same thing into the flutter console i get the following message:

```
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Basically is there anyone who can help me fix these problems

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs on preparing an Android app for release](https://flutter.io/android-release/):

> **Note**: `keytool` may not be in your path. It is part of the Java JDK, which is installed as part of Android Studio. For the concrete path, run `flutter doctor -v` and see the path printed after ‘Java binary at:’, and then use that fully qualified path replacing `java` with `keytool`.

In my machine the tool is located in

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool
```